# Mounting XFS filesystem on Mac

Tags: mac, xfs

I would like to know if it is possible to mount an XFS filesystem on a Mac as I want to use XFS on my flash drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: It is not possibly natively. It could however be possible to find a port of the XFS filesystem to FUSE, which would be a hacky solution, but still work. As far as I remember though, there are no projects on porting XFS to OS X.

Comment: Thanks, I will not be able to so this though as I don't have admin privileges on the mac machine. Thanks again, RayQuang

Answer (score 7):

You can mount XFS under OS X in read-only mode using [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.com/) together with [Fuse-XFS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fusexfs/).

From author's [website](http://www.ahardy.za.net/Home/fusexfs):

> Fuse-xfs is a MacFuse (OSXFUSE) driver for XFS filesystems. This driver allows Mac OS 10.7 with OSXFUSE/MacFuse to mount XFS filesystems in read only mode.
>
> The journal is ignored, but basic read only operations should work fine.
>
> This software should be considered alpha, and provides no guarantees that the XFS filesystem remains unaltered (although the code does not support writing in any way). Use of the software is entirely at the users own risk.

Answer (score 0):

A complicated solution would be to use a virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) run a linux in that and use it to do your filesystem operations.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a recent documentation that states whether you need administrator privileges for the install.

Comment: Actually I do this all the time for external drives.  You can have VirtualBox passthrough USB devices to Linux.  But yes, you do have to have administrator privs to install VB on the system.

Comment: @Angelo You can even mount XFS in the VM and then share the mountpoint to the macOS host!

Answer (score 0):

Using OSXFUSE together with Fuse-XFS works BUT is very slow.
Booting Linux on the Mac (USB "live" linux) works FAST!